# make value of the variable A = B unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Someone here is a gallows.
I have the following problem. I have two classes. .a class ListPainel.
and the class Items Requirements.

in class ListPainel I have the following:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
public GameObject slotPrafab;
public int numeroDeItensDisp;
public int numeroDeItensTotal;
}
public List<Item> itemList;
```

etc etc...

and in the class RequirementsItems I have the following:
Only public variables so that I can change in the inspector unity.

```
public Sprite imageNewItem;
public Image imageItem;
public Text req;
public string barra;
public int numberReqDisp;
public int numberReqTotal;
public static Item painel;
```

etc etc...

and I need the value of the variable / numberReqDisp; be = number of items; of the class listPainel ... so I'll delude this way:

```
numberReqDisp = painel.numeroDeItensDisp;
```

and what happens. in my unity. the values do not change. and it gives error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

.. and to make clear the class items required is attached to a prefab.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is in Portuguese

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to translate. I do not speak English

Comment: Use Stack Overflow em Portugues :)

Comment: Jon Skeet was here ;)

Answer (score 1):

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" means that it is not initialized. You can do it like that. But also don't forget to assign the values of painel. Like that:

```
public static Item painel = new Item();
painel.slotPrafab = ...
```

Or define a constructor for doing so.

Comment: this solved the error. but the values of the variables are not the same.

Comment: I made this shape but it still does not work for me.                
      numberReqDisp = painel.numeroDeItensDisp;

Comment: You need to assign a value to the field from painel like that  `painel.numeroDeItensDisp = 0;`